# VB.Net sorting files in a directory by natural date order

Tags: vb.net

I have a directory with many Excel files named [MMM yyyy].xlsx:

Jan 2012.xlsx

Feb 2012.xlsx

...... etc...

May 2022.xlsx

I have the the following code that must be adjusted to sort by natural date order, rather than file write time:

```
 Dim dir = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(MY_PATH).GetFiles("*.xlsx", 
     IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderBy(Function(x) x.LastWriteTime).Reverse


 For Each f As System.IO.FileInfo In dir    
 //code
 Next
```

Thank you

Comment: Look at the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method, which will let you use the `MMM yyyy` format string.

Comment: Also... since the date is now embedded in the name do you still need other `FileInfo` data inside the loop, or is the FileName enough? This might let us reduce RAM use and save on some disk I/O is we can switch to just file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Dim dir = New DirectoryInfo(MY_PATH).
    EnumerateFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
    OrderByDescending(Function(x) DateTime.ParseExact(x.Name.Replace(".xlsx", ""), "MMM yyyy", Nothing)

For Each f As FileInfo In dir    
    ' code
Next
```

Or this if you only need file names inside the loop, which might be a little faster:

```
Dim dir = New Directory(MY_PATH).
    EnumerateFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
    OrderByDescending(Function(x) DateTime.ParseExact(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x), "MMM yyyy", Nothing)

For Each f As String In dir    
    ' code
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Joel, your help is greatly appreciated. i did a small adjustment:     Dim dir = New DirectoryInfo(MY_PATH).EnumerateFiles("*.xlsx").OrderByDescending(Function(x) Date.ParseExact("01 " & x.Name.Replace(".xlsx", ""), "MMM yyyy", Nothing)) but still I am getting an error: System.FormatException: 'String '01 Apr 2012' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it was a space in the date string that need trimmed. Thanks again for your kind help! Marked as solution